# How to access request information inside the app directory, like with getServerSideProps context parameter?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

Basically, I want to be able to see the request data from my component. I've tried searching through the docs but haven't found anything.

If I can't do that, is there any other way I can do so?

And for context, I am trying to check if the request has the token in its body and checking if it is right and redirecting it to the right site

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `app` dir, you can acces request headers and cookies with `headers()`, and `cookies()` functions. On the migration from the `pages` to the `app` folder [guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration), they say the following:

> The `app` directory exposes new read-only functions to retrieve request data:
>
> [`headers()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/headers): Based on the Web Headers API, and can be used inside [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials) to retrieve request headers.
>
> [`cookies()`](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/cookies): Based on the Web Cookies API, and can be used inside [Server Components](https://nextjs.org/docs/getting-started/react-essentials) to retrieve cookies.

```js
// app/page.js

import { cookies, headers } from 'next/headers'
 
async function getData() {
  const authHeader = headers().get('authorization')
 
  return '...'
}
 
export default async function Page() {
  // You can use `cookies()` or `headers()` inside Server Components
  // directly or in your data fetching function
  const theme = cookies().get('theme')
  const data = await getData()
  return '...'
}
```